# A tag hidden using angular '[attr.aria-hidden]' is still accessible and clickable using tab and enter

Tags: javascript, html, angular, wai-aria

I have an a tag which has conditional [attr.aria-hidden] as displayed below:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="landing-login-btn" href="#"
   *ngIf="!loggedInState"
   (click)="openLoginModal()"
   [attr.aria-hidden]="navigateToNext" 
   [innerHTML]="secondaryBtn">
</a>
```

After event execution(button click):

1. 'a' tag is not visible on screen
2. In Dev tools, I can see that a tag has 'aria-hidden' set to true.

However, on tabbing, this tag is still accessible and can be clicked using 'enter'. 
What am I missing here? 
Do I need to completely hide the button in order to stop it from clicking?

Comment: if you want to show button to user but not let them click then can use `disabled` property or you don't then can use proper `ngIf` condition so that it will only be visible when condition is true

Comment: here `!loggedInState` returns true, so the element is still in the dom. why dont you make use of `navigateToNext` so the element wont show up in the dom

Comment: actually This is an existing application with lots of developers working on same code base. The application contains the 'ngIf' with an existing flag, I dont wish to modify that. I just wish that the button should not be clickable when aria-hidden is true. However, setting up aria-hidden to true does not seem to disable the button from tabbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, on tabbing, this tag is still accessible and can be clicked using 'enter'.

That is correct.  The [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden) attribute is a hint to screen readers that the element should not be surfaced to screen readers.  That is, it is "hidden" from screen readers.

However, [ARIA attributes do **not** provide any kind of behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#aria-does-nothing).  That is, setting `aria-hidden="true"` will not visibly hide the element nor will it prevent focus from moving to it.  If you want the `<a>` hidden for everyone, just use CSS `display:none`.  You won't need `aria-hidden` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [attr.aria-hidden]="navigateToNext? 'hidden' : null" like

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="landing-login-btn" href="#"
                                    *ngIf="!loggedInState"
                                    (click)="openLoginModal()"
                                    [attr.aria-hidden]="navigateToNext? 'hidden' : null"
                                    [innerHTML]="secondaryBtn"></a>
```